# Why using SVM in Python in these two different ways gives a very different accuracy scores?

Tags: python, svm

Using Python and SVM, I applied these two pieces of codes:

First I applied this code with a dataset

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import cohen_kappa_score
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC

model = LinearSVC(class_weight='balanced',C=0.01, penalty='l2').fit(X_, y)
y_preds = model.predict(X_)
report = classification_report( y, y_preds )
print(report)
print(cohen_kappa_score(y, y_preds),'\n', accuracy_score(y, y_preds), \n',confusion_matrix(y, y_preds))
```

This gives me this accuracy : `0.9485714285714286`

Second I applied this code with exactly same dataset again

```
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

models = [
    LinearSVC(class_weight='balanced',C=0.01, penalty='l2', loss='squared_hinge'),
]
CV = 5
cv_df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(CV * len(models)))
entries = []
for model in models:
    model_name = model.__class__.__name__
    accuracies = cross_val_score(model, X_, y, scoring='accuracy', cv=CV)
    for fold_idx, accuracy in enumerate(accuracies):
        entries.append((model_name, fold_idx, accuracy))
cv_df = pd.DataFrame(entries, columns=['model_name', 'fold_idx', 'accuracy'])
cv_df.groupby('model_name').accuracy.mean()
```

The accuracy is different: `0.797090`

Where are my mistakes?

Which code is correct if any?

How to calculate precision and recall after cross-validation as in the 2nd code?

Comment: Hi. Do you know what cross validation means? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics) In the 1st, you only do 1 time prediction & accuracy calculation. While in the 2nd code you do 5 times predictions & accuracy calculations (with different chunks of dataset) then get the mean/average of the accuracy scores. In other words, the 2nd code gives more reliable accuracy score.

Comment: Thank you, do you know how to calculate precision and recall after cross-validation like in the 2nd code? or that can be only possible without cross-validation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the 1st code, you only do 1 time prediction & accuracy calculation. While in the 2nd code you do 5 times predictions & accuracy calculations (with different chunks of dataset) then get the mean/average of the accuracy scores. In other words, the 2nd code gives more reliable accuracy score.

As for your other question, if you want to do cross validation with multiple metrics, you can use [`cross_validate()`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate.html) instead of `cross_val_score()`:

```
scores = cross_validate(model, X, y, scoring=('precision', 'recall'))
print(scores['precision'])      
print(scores['recall'])
```